# Is there a JS Module loader that loads into global namespace?

Tags: javascript

I would like to achieve something like so - JS File 1:

```
class Polygon {
...
}
```

JS file 2:

```
import 'Polygon.js'

class Square extends Polygon {
...
}
```

Is there any module loading framework that would allow me to do this (without having to encapsulate the imports from 'Polygon.js' inside a variable)

Comment: You could do `window.Polygon = class {}` (in a browser environment) if you want to keep it simple.

Comment: I don't think you need the `.js` file extension, but it might depend on your module loader.

Comment: Can you modify Polygon.js?

Comment: I can modify Polygon.js. How?